# List of Dates ordered in a certain way

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of dates (strings in the format `yyyyMM`) as follows:

```
201608
201609
201610
201708
201709
201710
```

I'd like to reorder them to be as follows:

```
201608
201708
201609
201709
201610
201710
```

I thought I could reverse the strings (i.e. `016102`) to order them *but* obviously with a month >= 10 it causes issues resulting in the list coming out like:

```
201610
201710
201608
201708
201609
201709
```

I tried the following: 
`MyList.OrderBy(n => string.Concat(n.datestring.Reverse())).Select(n => n);`

Is there a nice succinct way of doing this (LINQ would be nice)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't want to reverse the strings, you want to slice it into two substrings, year and month and then order by those separately (month, then year).  Try something like `myList.OrderBy(s => s.Substring(4)).ThenBy(s => s.Substring(0, 4))`

Comment: So, to be clear, you want them ordered by month and then by year?  Or, do you just want them in the order that you say.  Consider keep date-ish and time-ish things as either DateTimes or TimeSpans.  They are much easier to handle.  However, @BrianRogers' solution is probably the way to go (assuming that I've correctly guessed your problem statement)

Comment: Yes that’s the ticket Brian. It’s late. I had a brain fart! Thanks for unsticking me! I’ll give that a go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ, you order by the two digit month then the year (and month, but that shouldn't matter):

```
var ans = src.OrderBy(s => s.Substring(4)).ThenBy(s => s);
```

Comment: Nice one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd cheat and order by dates personally, via an Extension Method:

New class:

```
public static class DateOperations
{
    public static List<DateTime> GetDates(this List<string> dateStrings)
    {
        List<DateTime> asDates = new List<DateTime>();
        dateStrings.ForEach(e =>
        asDates.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(e, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None))
        );

        return asDates;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var ordered = myList.GetDates().OrderBy(ord => ord.Month).ThenBy(then => then.Year);
```

And then when I needed the string again I'd use:

```
date[_whateverAccessorReally].ToString("yyyyMM");
```